# The correct way to implement ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2008

I am trying to use ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject to add a timer to a set of threads.  I create 9 threads and am trying to give each of them an equal chance of operation as at the moment there seems to be a little starvation going on if I just add them to the thread pool.  I am also trying to implement a manual reset event as I want all 9 threads to exit before continuing.

What is the best way to ensure that each thread in the threadpool gets an equal chance at running as the function that I am calling has a loop and it seems that each thread (or whichever one runs first) gets stuck in it and the others don't get a chance to run.

```
resetEvents = new ManualResetEvent[table_seats]; 
            //Spawn 9 threads
            for (int i = 0; i < table_seats; i++)
            {
                resetEvents[i] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
                //AutoResetEvent ev = new AutoResetEvent(false);
                RegisteredWaitHandle handle = ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(autoEvent, ObserveSeat, (object)i, 100, false);
            }

            //wait for threads to exit
            WaitHandle.WaitAll(resetEvents);
```

However, it doesn't matter if I use resetEvents[] or ev neither seem to work properly.  Am I able to implement this or am I (probably) misunderstanding how they should work.

Thanks, R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would not use the `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` for this purpose. The patterns I am going to describe here require the [Reactive Extensions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896.aspx) download since you are using .NET v3.5.

First, to wait for all work items from the `ThreadPool` to complete use the `CountdownEvent` class. This is a lot more elegant and scalable than using multiple `ManualResetEvent` instances. Plus, the `WaitHandle.WaitAll` method is limited to 64 handles.

```
var finished = new CountdownEvent(1);
for (int i = 0; i < table_seats; i++)
{
  finished.AddCount();
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(ObserveSeat);
    (state) =>
    {
      try
      {
        ObserveSeat(state);
      }
      finally
      {
        finished.Signal();
      }
    }, i);
}
finished.Signal();
finished.Wait();
```

Second, you could try calling `Thread.Sleep(0)` after several iterations of the loop to force a context switch so that the current thread yields to another. If you want a considerably more complex coordination strategy then use the `Barrier` class. Add another parameter to your `ObserveSeat` function which accepts this synchronization mechanism. You could supply it by capturing it in the lambda expression in the code above.

```
public void ObserveSeat(object state, Barrier barrier)
{
  barrier.AddParticipant();
  try
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_ITERATIONS; i++)
    {
      if (i % AMOUNT == 0)
      {
        // Let the other threads know we are done with this phase and wait
        // for them to catch up.
        barrier.SignalAndWait();
      }
      // Perform your work here.
    }
  }
  finally
  {
    barrier.RemoveParticipant();
  }
}
```

Note that although this approach would certainly prevent the starvation issue it might limit the throughput of the threads. Calling `SignalAndWait` too much might cause a lot of unnecessary context switching, but calling it too little might cause a lot of unnecessary waiting. You would probably have to tune `AMOUNT` to get the optimal balance of throughput and starvation. I suspect there might be a simple way to do the tuning dynamically.

Comment: Thanks, I haven't had time to test this yet but thanks Brian for the answer.